# Laravel insert collection in db

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have retrieved some data from db using:

```
$filtered = DB::table('tmp_table')->distinct()->select('type','description','note')->get();
```

and I would like to insert what I have retrieved in another table like:

```
DB::table('tmp_other')->insert($filtered);
```

but I receive thie error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given
```

which is the best way to do this?

Comment: `DB::table('tmp_other')->insert($filtered->toArray());` should work.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione well ... did you understand, what was written in the error message?

Comment: The Eloquent tag does not apply here does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL way to do blunk inserts of this is something more native like :

```
DB::insert(
      "INSERT INTO tmp_other (type,description,note) 
       SELECT DISTINCT type,description,note FROM tmp_table"
);
```

This will avoid the whole transfer to webserver/transfer back to the SQL server process.

Comment: Simplest ideas are the best!

Answer (score 2):

this will do the trick for you try this :)

```
$filtered = DB::table('tmp_table')->distinct()->select('type','description','note')->get();
$filtered->toArray();

DB::table('tmp_other')->insert($filtered);
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working,Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: The problem with this code is that `toArray()` _returns_ the array, it does not convert the object. You can do one of the following: add `toArray()` on the `get()`,  reassign the `$filtered` variable with the returned array from `toArray()` or call `toArray` inside the parameter list of the `insert(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick :)

```
$filtered = DB::table('tmp_table')->distinct()->select('type','description','note')->get()->toArray();
$to_fill = [];
foreach($filtered as $record) {
  $to_fill[] = (array)$record;
}

DB::table('tmp_other')->insert($to_fill);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one line, like this:

```
Region::insert($tempCollection->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that:

```php
Region::insert($tempCollection->toArray());
```

Doesn't work when you have appends in the model. This does not happen if you use getAttributes on each model. Therefore, this should be safe:

```php
Region::insert($tempCollection->map(fn($x) => $x->getAttributes())->toArray()
```